# What is the full conda-forge channel url?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I'm trying to install `conda-forge` packages from within an Anaconda Enterprise environment and the "standard" approach is failing because `conda` is searching relative to our enterprise anaconda instance, rather than using the external anaconda url. What is the full url for the `conda-forge` channel?

The default base url for `conda` channels in this environment is `https://wwwdesign.anaconda.company.com/repository/conda`, so when I use

```
channels:
    - conda-forge
```

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the requested channel with url: https://wwwdesign.anaconda.company.com/repository/conda/conda-forge
```

I can force `conda` to look in the default public anaconda channel by adding `http://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main`, but I can't find the equivalent url for `conda-forge`. I tried `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/repo`, but it doesn't work (similar error to above).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Short Answer**
`conda-forge`'s fully resolved url is `https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/`

**How I found it**
Among other information, `conda info` spits out the full channel URLs that you've configured in conda. I added `conda-forge` to my workstation's `conda` with `conda config --add channels conda-forge` and ran `conda info`. You'll get two urls for each channel, an `<OS>-64` and `noarch`, but it seems like you can snip that off and use `https://conda.anaconda.org/<channel-name>/` .