# Which URL to use for conda repositories published through nexus repository manager, nxrm

Tags: anaconda, conda, nexus

I can easily publish the main conda repo in Nexus Repository Manager. The URL used is this:

```
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs
```

But how do I figure out which URL to use for publishing e.g. conda-forge or the conda R channel?

```
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/pkgs
```

does not work. Am I wrong in thinking there should be a repodata.json in the root of the URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the full conda-forge channel url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711498/what-is-the-full-conda-forge-channel-url)

Comment: No, unfortunately not . https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge will result in a 404. There are repodata.json files in https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch and in https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64, but those also results in 404

Answer (score 1):

yes same here adding : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge in nexus conda-forge repo made a 404

Answer (score 1):

I found out.

The url for conda-forge is

```
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/
```

The url for the local repo is this (assuming the repo is named conda_forge)

```
http://localhost:8081/repository/conda_forge
```

The webinterface of Nexus Repository Manager claims there should be a /main in the end of the local url, but this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to include conda-forge as a raw proxy. While this can be helpful. (But it still be slow, possibly due to a poor network connection.)